# HTML, set column width for multiple tables based on the widest column in any of these tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, html-table

Using python I am generating a html page with multiple tables which all have the same amount of columns. Also all of these columns hold the same type of data.

The page I am generating is OK, but I would like to boost the legibility by making all the tables same width, currently each table have either different width, or the text is overflowing the columns.

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  table th {
    padding: .2em 1em;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  
  table td {
    padding: .2em 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  table th:nth-child(1) { width: 100px !important; }
  table th:nth-child(2) { width: 250px !important; }
  table th:nth-child(3) { width: 100px !important; }
  table th:nth-child(4) { width: 100px !important; }
  table th:nth-child(5) { width: 250px !important; }
  table th:nth-child(6) { width: 100px !important; }
  table th:nth-child(7) { width: 100px !important; }
  table th:nth-child(8) { width: 100px !important; }
  table th:nth-child(9) { width: 100px !important; }
  table th:nth-child(10) { width: 100px !important; }

  table td:nth-child(1) { width: 100px !important; }
  table td:nth-child(2) { width: 250px !important; }
  table td:nth-child(3) { width: 100px !important; }
  table td:nth-child(4) { width: 100px !important; }
  table td:nth-child(5) { width: 250px !important; }
  table td:nth-child(6) { width: 100px !important; }
  table td:nth-child(7) { width: 100px !important; }
  table td:nth-child(8) { width: 100px !important; }
  table td:nth-child(9) { width: 100px !important; }
  table td:nth-child(10) { width: 100px !important; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
  <title>Navigation</title>
  <style>
    code{white-space: pre-wrap;}
    span.smallcaps{font-variant: small-caps;}
    span.underline{text-decoration: underline;}
    div.column{display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 50%;}
    div.hanging-indent{margin-left: 1.5em; text-indent: -1.5em;}
    ul.task-list{list-style: none;}
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="template.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="suite-test-cases">Suite test cases</h1>
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th>Test Case</th>
<th>Test Case<br>Name</th>
<th>Owner</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Test Case<br>Description</th>
<th>Design</th>
<th>Preconditions</th>
<th>Depends on</th>
<th>Dependencies</th>
<th>Comment</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td>ID.PFIBD1</td>
<td>Fill in billing details</td>
<td></td>
<td>Done</td>
<td>Log into application with user without paid subscription and create new subscription</td>
<td>1. Log In (more in ID.CCU1)<br>2. Assert visibility of non active subscription pop-up<br>3. Enter the billing details<br>4. Await the successfull message confirmation</td>
<td>1. Site must be up<br>2. Test user must exist<br>3. Test user must not have active subscription</td>
<td>ID.CCU1</td>
<td>1. ID.PUBI1<br>2. ID.PDBI1<br>3. ID.PFIBD4</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h1 id="suite-test-cases-1">Suite test cases</h1>
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th>Test Case</th>
<th>Test Case<br>Name</th>
<th>Owner</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Test Case<br>Description</th>
<th>Design</th>
<th>Preconditions</th>
<th>Depends on</th>
<th>Dependencies</th>
<th>Comment</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td>ID.CCU2</td>
<td>Create User</td>
<td></td>
<td>WIP</td>
<td>Create single unique user</td>
<td>1. Goto settings screen<br>2. Wait until all elements visible<br>3. Enter newly generated email into the Create User field<br>4. Wait for aside menu to be visible<br>5. Fill in all the fields in aside menu<br>6. Create an user<br>7. Check Create User Action was successful</td>
<td>1. Site must be up<br>2. Test user has to have privileges to create a role<br>3. To be created test user must not exist</td>
<td>ID.CCU1</td>
<td>1. ID.DDU1<br>2. ID.UUU1<br>3. ID.UUU2</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run the MWE you can see that:

1. Both tables are different width
2. Columns in both tables have different width

So my goal is to:

1. Make table same width (can be wider than the width of the page because I do not want to break text in lists)
2. Make all the columns of the same type, so for example **Test case name** (second column) same width in all of the tables (I now have around 10 of these tables and I want to keep them separate)

The width should for all the columns in all of the tables be determined by the widest column in any of these tables, so for example the **Test case name** column should *inherit* the width of **Test case name** column in the first table.

So it might for example look like this:

[image]

Meaning that, just to name few:

1. Test Case Name (second colum) width for all tables was set by the **first** table
2. Owner (third column) width for all tables was set by the **second** table
3. Test Case Descriptin (fifth column) width for all tables was set by the **first table**

Note that the widest column can be in any of the tables, so I am looking for dynamic solution.

I initially thought about manually setting the width in the CSS, therefore the `table th:nth-child(1) { width: 100px !important; }` part, however I soon realized this is not scalable.

I believe I need some javascript to solve this, unfortunately I do not know where to begin. I tried replicating some examples I found on the internet, but unfortunately these did not work, I suppose because my table is wider.

Could you please help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted the columns of the two tables with jQuery.

---

```js
$('#table2 th').each(function(idx) {
  var w1 = $('#table1 thead tr').children("th:eq(" + idx + ")").width();
  var w2 = $(this).width();
  if (w1 > w2)
    $(this).css("min-width", w1 + "px");
  else if (w2 > w1)
    $('#table1 thead tr').children("th:eq(" + idx + ")").css("min-width", w2 + "px");
});
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
  padding: .2em 1em;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table td {
  padding: .2em 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table th:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

table th:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 250px;
}

table th:nth-child(3) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

table th:nth-child(4) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

table th:nth-child(5) {
  min-width: 250px;
}

table th:nth-child(6) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

table th:nth-child(7) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

table th:nth-child(8) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

table th:nth-child(9) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

table th:nth-child(10) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

table td {
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

span.smallcaps {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

span.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div.column {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
}

div.hanging-indent {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  text-indent: -1.5em;
}

ul.task-list {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="suite-test-cases">Suite test cases</h1>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Test Case</th>
      <th>Test Case<br>Name</th>
      <th>Owner</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Test Case<br>Description</th>
      <th>Design</th>
      <th>Preconditions</th>
      <th>Depends on</th>
      <th>Dependencies</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>ID.PFIBD1</td>
      <td>Fill in billing details</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Done</td>
      <td>Log into application with user without paid subscription and create new subscription</td>
      <td>1. Log In (more in ID.CCU1)<br>2. Assert visibility of non active subscription pop-up<br>3. Enter the billing details<br>4. Await the successfull message confirmation</td>
      <td>1. Site must be up<br>2. Test user must exist<br>3. Test user must not have active subscription</td>
      <td>ID.CCU1</td>
      <td>1. ID.PUBI1<br>2. ID.PDBI1<br>3. ID.PFIBD4</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h1 id="suite-test-cases-1">Suite test cases</h1>
<table id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Test Case</th>
      <th>Test Case<br>Name</th>
      <th>Owner</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Test Case<br>Description</th>
      <th>Design</th>
      <th>Preconditions</th>
      <th>Depends on</th>
      <th>Dependencies</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>ID.CCU2</td>
      <td>Create User</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>WIP</td>
      <td>Create single unique user</td>
      <td>1. Goto settings screen<br>2. Wait until all elements visible<br>3. Enter newly generated email into the Create User field<br>4. Wait for aside menu to be visible<br>5. Fill in all the fields in aside menu<br>6. Create an user<br>7. Check Create User Action was successful</td>
      <td>1. Site must be up<br>2. Test user has to have privileges to create a role<br>3. To be created test user must not exist</td>
      <td>ID.CCU1</td>
      <td>1. ID.DDU1<br>2. ID.UUU1<br>3. ID.UUU2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @meysam asadi, thank you, I achieved similar thing when trying this myself, unfortunately I can not use this, as I do not want the lines to break, because I have lists there, in which I would like to keep individual items, for clarity reason, on the same line. I realize that maybe from UX point of view, having such wide table is not ideal, but in this situation I really do not want to break the items into multiple lines.

Comment: I modified the code. According to what you wanted. I did this with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @meysam asadi, in the end I managed to do exactly what I wanted by slighty modifying your answer. I used an array to find the highest values for each column and then I applied the value to all the corresponding columns, thanks again for your help.